Find the Key range that exists in an `enquiring range` in std::map in C++
How do I find if I have any keys within a range . I am trying below:
The goal is to get -2 and 2 as the key boundary range (that actually exists in the map) within enquiry range [-3,3]
std::map<int, char> m{ {-2,'B'}, {1, 'C'},  {2, 'A'}};

auto itCurrent = m.lower_bound(-3);
auto itNext = m.upper_bound(-3);

auto it1 = m.lower_bound(3);
auto it2 = m.upper_bound(3);

I do get value -2 for itCurrent and  itNext but why am I getting end for it1 and it2 both. I was expecting  m.lower_bound(3) should return 2.

With [-3, +3] do you mean the closed interval (both limits included) ? Because C and C++ and most related languages use half-open intervals by default, e.g. [-3, +3) with -3 included and +3 not. Cf array bounds, int a[5] has a[0] to a[4] but not a[5].

Probably the same root misunderstanding as rationale for std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound?. The diagram in A: Difference between upper_bound and lower_bound in stl might help. (Should this be marked a duplicate of those?)

@MSalters In other words I need to find nearest existing keys in my range (3,3) or [-3,3] . So I want to get the key -2 and 2 as they exist in the map and in my enquiring range.

@GauravK I rolled back your edit because you should not edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answer(s). Please post a new question.

Also if the range does not contain too many keys, you can simply iterate on them and select the ones you need based on any criterion.

@GauravK: I understand that +2 and -2 are definitely in the range. But since you write " my range (3,3) or [-3,3]" I have to conclude that you're not sure about open vs closed, but you certainly don't mean the half-open interval [-3, +3) which is the usual C++ convention. That explains why you're seeing this behavior, lower_bound and upper_bound return the same type of half-open interval here.

@MSalters I know difference between [-3,3], (-3,3) or [-3,3). In my specific example it does not matter as the keys are in range [-2,2]. And hence said enquiry range (3,3) or [-3,3]

@GauravK: Programming the easy cases is easy. Getting the edge cases right is hard. And in this case, we're talking about the literal edges of the interval. If you can't even define what your function is supposed to do, how can we tell you how to implement it? Also, do consider what your function is supposed to do when the map is empty, for instance - a specification can't just ignore that.

As you can see in the std::map::lower_bound documentation:

Return value
Iterator pointing to the first element that is not less than key. If
no such element is found, a past-the-end iterator (see end()) is
returned.

(emphasis is mine)
You don't have a key that is not less than 3, and therfore m.lower_bound(3) returns end().
Similarly regarding std::map::upper_bound:

Return value
Iterator pointing to the first element that is greater than key. If no
such element is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is returned.

(emphasis is mine)
You don't have a key that is greater than 3, and so m.upper_bound(3) returns end().
This also makes sense for your purpose of finding elements in a range:
All of your elements are before the end of the range (and included in it) - which is what the end() return value signifies.
For a closed range like [-3,3], all the elements from m.lower_bound(-3), up to (but not including) m.upper_bound(3) are in the range.
If you need the ones that are the closest to the range's borders they are:
auto it_low = m.lower_bound(-3);
and
auto it_high = m.upper_bound(3); std::advance(it_high , -1);
(std::advance with -1 is used to get one element before the iterator that is just after the range).

How do I find the nearest keys in the range [-3,3] ? Is there an easy way.

I think that all the elements from itCurrent up to (but not including it2) are in the range.

I need to find the nearest keys to -3 and 3

If you need to find one nearest key, it's either itCurrent, or one before it2. But your question was how to find all keys in a range (which I believe I answered) - isn't it ? Maybe you can post a new question ?

I edit the post.

@GauravK you should not edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answer(s). You should post a new question.
